# Using typescript with JSX element to set div height?

Tags: javascript, html, css, typescript, jsx

How can I set the height of a div to say 40% of the height of another div? Currently I am using typescript and am generating a JSX element, I also have a scss file at my disposal.

Comment: Do you need to do that dynamically? You can specify `height: 40%` in css.